# In $G(n,p)$, if $p = \omega(n^{-1/2})$, then the domination number $\gamma(G(n,p)) = \Omega(p^{-1}\text{log}(np))$ with high probability.

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification, random-graphs, extremal-combinatorics, probabilistic-method

> Given a graph $G$, the domination number $\gamma(G)$ is the size of the smallest dominating set in $V(G)$.

I’m still working on this problem so I’d like to ask for comments on my approach below, and possibly some hints. Also I find myself frequently stuck when studying probabilistic method problems, since even the lecture content employs a lot of seemingly random tricks but not a “big picture” theory, so some ideas on how to think about these kinds of problems would be appreciated.

Let $\gamma = \gamma(G(n,p))$. We want to show that
\begin{align}
&\text{lim}_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(\gamma = \Omega(p^{-1}\text{log}(np))) = 1 \\
\text{i.e. } &\text{lim}_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{P}(\gamma \geq kp^{-1}\text{log}(np)) = 1, \text{for some constant $k$} \\
\text{i.e. } &\text{lim}_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(\exists S \subset V(G), |S| < kp^{-1}\text{log}(np), S \text{ is a dominating set}) = 0
\end{align}

Let $S$ be an arbitrary set of vertices, $|S| < kp^{-1}\text{log}(np)$. $S$ is not a dominating set if there exists $u \in (V \setminus S)$ s.t. $\forall s \in S, \{s,u\} \notin E(G)$.

Now for some $u \in G$
$$\mathbb{P}(\text{$u$ is not dominated by $S$}) = \left(1 - \frac{|S|}{n} \right)(1 - p)^{|S|},$$
i.e. $u$ is not in $S$ and none of the vertices in $S$ is a neighbour of $u$.

From here I can do a few other calculations, and I was thinking of using the union bounds twice to arrive at the lim statement. Unfortunately the assumption that $p = \omega(n^{-1/2})$ doesn’t help with this approach.

Comment: You should not have a factor of $1 - \frac{|S|}{n}$, because $u$ and $S$ are not random: only the edges are random.

Comment: I was thinking of $S$ as a random set sampled from $V$. But if we don’t do that, I suppose I need to find a way to account for the cases where $u \in S$?

Comment: As a general matter, you're not going to be able to prove that *no* set $S$ exists by randomly sampling $S$. That's how you prove that something does exist. To prove that no set exists, with high probability, you want to union bound over all $S$, for example.

Comment: But accounting for cases where $u \in S$ is easy. Given a fixed set $S$, we can write down an exact probability that $S$ is dominating: for each of the $n-|S|$ vertices not in $S$, we want at least one edge from $S$ to exist, and these events are independent.